# How to decide the Temperature range of an IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit, thermal

I am using a MAX3241E ic in a device that has to run 24x7 out in the open. I am facing a problem deciding the temperature range of the the IC. Since it is out in the open, the ic has to withstand the heat from the sun plus the heating effect due to losses and resistances, etc. I am living in Delhi, India and here the temperature easily reaches 45 degrees. This ic that I have choosen can bear a max temp of 70 degrees. Should I use this ic or should I go for a higher temperature one? Also please tell how should one decide the max temperature of any ic?

Datasheet of the IC: - http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/256/MAX3222E-MAX3246E-99333.pdf

Comment: Additional Question: 
What is the difference between the IC which can support 0-70°C and the one that support -40-85°C? Do they have the same die? Case material?

Comment: The wider temperature range is usually Automotive (or military or space qualified) and batch selected to have lower temperature rates leakage currents or closer tolerances and may use slightly more expensive encapsulation. I would use these and check the temperature derating if you expect output shorts.

Comment: You will usually find three grades, commercial 0 to +70 degrees (cheap plastic capsules), industrial/automotive -25 to +85 degrees (better qualification and more effort in the bonding inside plastic capsules) and military/aerospace -40 to +125 degrees (full on ceramic capsules).

Comment: @Winny: I have rarely seen -25 to 85; -40 to +85 is *far* more common.

Comment: @PeterSmith You are correct. I got -25 from industrial products, usually where electolytic caps set the lower bar. -40 for the chips inside it though.

Comment: The outside temperature is relevant, but what is even more relevant is the temperature that will be in the *casing of the device*. So if it is a big 500W class-A amp, that will be different than if the only other component on the board is a small MCU that dissipates 100mW. What device is it?

Comment: It is just a custom circuit with 3 rs232 ports and a single mcu and a single max3232 3 channel ic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must select a chip with more than 70°C max temperature.

I can't give you calculation but in my experience a body placed in face of the sun could reach, in summer, 60-80°C, and if the ambient's temperature is so high as you say the heat dissipation is not enough efficient.

Answer (score 0):

For long life, remember that the minimum temperature you can use for a part is best, so take care mounting and packaging.  The part you have chosen will dissipate a watt or more if the design requires it, so the temperature rise associated with the application must be added to the part temperature.  In general, the temperature rise can be considered constant, so you can measure the part temperature at ambient and expect the difference between ambient and this temperature to remain the same.

This part should be ok at 35C ambient as long as you are not in a package where the part is not packaged in a manner that creates a "hot spot."  Remember that if you have a surface in direct sunlight or on the dashboard of a car, you can approach or exceed 70C.  The 70C rating is calculated at a specific (maximum) power rating. But you can always increase expected life by limiting the power the part must dissipate, by limiting the load or duty cycle.

Comment: Well I got the ambient temperature wrong in the question. It is 45 degrees. Now will the ic be ok?